# Multiprocessing on a JSON API for loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm finding that querying the following is taking up most of the load time, is there any way to multiprocess this? The lists and variables have already been defined previously and have data contained

```
for i in range(len(allTrainDataList)):
      allTrainsRouteJSON = requests.get('https://api.com/'+mergeAllTrainDataList[i]+'/'+date,
                        auth=('username', 'password'))
      allTrainServiceJson = allTrainsRouteJSON.json()
      listOfAllStations=[]

      try: noSchedule = str(allTrainServiceJson['error'])
      except: noSchedule="FALSE"

      if noSchedule=="FALSE":

#Sanity check - Was main station on the planned route?
        for j in allTrainServiceJson['locations']:

  #Potentially put the if statements here to run each of the route defs    
            listOfAllStations.append(str(j['crs'])+mergeAllTrainDataList[i])
            toBeChecked=[fromStation+allTrainDataList[i],toStation+mergeAllTrainDataList[i]]
            toBeChecked2=[returnFromStation+allTrainDataList[i],returnToStation+mergeAllTrainDataList[i]]

            if contains_in_order(listOfAllStations,toBeChecked):
              allTrainDataListFinal.append(mergeAllTrainDataList[i])       
            if contains_in_order(listOfAllStations,toBeChecked2):
              allTrainDataListFinal2.append(mergeAllTrainDataList[i])
```

Comment: There are quite a few ways to run requests in parallel. Try the keywords "threading" or "asyncio" on Google.

Comment: If you know how to turn the whole inside of this loop into a function, you can just use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` and call `ex.map(func, allTrainDataList)`. The examples in the docs for the `concurrent.futures` module in the stdlib are pretty simple, so hopefully you can work it out from there. If you get stuck, or course, you can ask for help.

Comment: The only tricky bit is that you probably want the parallel task to return a value that the main thread can append to a list, instead of sharing that list between your threads. (I’m not sure whether that’s clear enough if you’ve never done threading before—if not, let me know what you need clarified and I’ll try.)

Comment: Actually, a simpler thought: you probably don’t need to parallelize the actual processing here, just waiting on the requests. So you can just make the task `return allTrainsRouteJSON.json())`, and put the rest of the code in a loop in the main thread that just waits on results from `futures.as_completed(fs)`, where `fs` is just a list of futures created in exactly the same way as the example in the docs.